how to perform pvalue t test and normalize a table in R
I have a table like that :
                      a_25    a_26    a_27    a_28    a_29    a_30
ENST00000673902.1       26      38      40      38      36      63
ENST00000618500.4        0       0       0       0       0       0
ENST00000420646.6        0      26       0     115       0     220
ENST00000394991.8     3496    2272    4848    2508    2427    3024
ENST00000336904.7       19       0      40      43      61       0
ENST00000394989.6        0       0      27       0       0      40
ENST00000673766.1      220     274     321     338     248     304
ENST00000673718.1       56     197     603     176     437      43
ENST00000674129.1      743     538    1047     202     276     269
ENST00000345009.8        0       0       0       0       0       0
ENST00000394986.5       85      97     277      10      41      63
ENST00000508895.5     3034    2152    5165    1231    1245    1814
ENST00000506244.5      554     283     276     247     248     182
ENST00000505199.5        0       0       0       0       0       0
ENST00000611107.1        0       0       0       0       0       0
ENST00000502987.5      113     128     213     127     139     144
ENST00000506691.1      212     170     397      87     106     126
ENSRNOT00000039247    1623    1230    2239    1413    1573    1611
ENSRNOT00000118428       0       0       0     106     119     132

I would like first to normalize it and then perform a t-test for the two conditions I have the one con1 (samples a_25 a_26 a_27) and the second con2 (samples a_28 a_29 a_30). How to do it in R ?
I tried to normalize with cpm
Norm_count <- edgeR::cpm(Counts,log10 = T)

But the result is strange big numbers ! What kind of normalization is proper and how to perform a t test for each ENST0000X lets say and export a pvalue to see the statistical significance between conditions in R ?

I don't understand what you mean by to normalize, if it is to have both samples with mean 0 and se 1 then the t test will give a p-value of 1, the data are a.s. equal. Also, with only 3 data points per sample, the t test or any other test cannot be of any use.

apply to each row an anonymous function that first checks the variances of each group of values, and if not zero run the t test. The results are output to a list and can be accessed as any other list.
con1_cols <- 1:3
con2_cols <- 4:6

tst_list <- apply(df1, 1L, \(x) {
  con1 <- x[con1_cols]
  con2 <- x[con2_cols]
  if(var(con1) > 0L && var(con2) > 0L) {
    t.test(con1, con2)
  } else invisible(NULL)
})

tst_list$ENST00000673902.1
#> 
#>  Welch Two Sample t-test
#> 
#> data:  con1 and con2
#> t = -1.1312, df = 2.9522, p-value = 0.3414
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -42.23167  20.23167
#> sample estimates:
#> mean of x mean of y 
#>  34.66667  45.66667
tst_list[[1]]
#> 
#>  Welch Two Sample t-test
#> 
#> data:  con1 and con2
#> t = -1.1312, df = 2.9522, p-value = 0.3414
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -42.23167  20.23167
#> sample estimates:
#> mean of x mean of y 
#>  34.66667  45.66667

Created on 2024-04-26 with reprex v2.1.0

The results
The list created is alist of objects of class "htest", see the help page for a description. You can now extract the results you want, below three examples.
# which tests are not null
ok <- !sapply(tst_list, is.null)

# extract test statistic
sapply(tst_list[ok], '[[', 'statistic')
#>  ENST00000673902.1.t  ENST00000420646.6.t  ENST00000394991.8.t 
#>           -1.1312254           -1.6063928            1.1546129 
#>  ENST00000336904.7.t  ENST00000394989.6.t  ENST00000673766.1.t 
#>           -0.6987039           -0.2693758           -0.6370820 
#>  ENST00000673718.1.t  ENST00000674129.1.t  ENST00000394986.5.t 
#>            0.3321883            3.5197006            1.7976798 
#>  ENST00000508895.5.t  ENST00000506244.5.t  ENST00000502987.5.t 
#>            2.2086705            1.5446044            0.4649906 
#>  ENST00000506691.1.t ENSRNOT00000039247.t 
#>            2.1708742            0.5503000

# extract p-values
sapply(tst_list[ok], '[[', 'p.value')
#>  ENST00000673902.1  ENST00000420646.6  ENST00000394991.8  ENST00000336904.7 
#>         0.34141555         0.24501497         0.35603099         0.52956853 
#>  ENST00000394989.6  ENST00000673766.1  ENST00000673718.1  ENST00000674129.1 
#>         0.80272247         0.55907404         0.75819180         0.06707388 
#>  ENST00000394986.5  ENST00000508895.5  ENST00000506244.5  ENST00000502987.5 
#>         0.20013352         0.14705681         0.24997864         0.68563111 
#>  ENST00000506691.1 ENSRNOT00000039247 
#>         0.15578057         0.63351503

# note the wide intervals
sapply(tst_list[ok], '[[', 'conf.int') |> 
  t() |>
  `colnames<-`(c("lower", "upper"))
#>                          lower      upper
#> ENST00000673902.1    -42.23167   20.23167
#> ENST00000420646.6   -369.61102  163.61102
#> ENST00000394991.8  -2085.30287 3856.63620
#> ENST00000336904.7    -79.01080   49.01080
#> ENST00000394989.6    -51.57161   42.90495
#> ENST00000673766.1   -134.43478   84.43478
#> ENST00000673718.1   -516.08890  649.42223
#> ENST00000674129.1    -88.25377 1142.25377
#> ENST00000394986.5   -133.44264  363.44264
#> ENST00000508895.5  -1614.07488 5654.74155
#> ENST00000506244.5   -222.43177  513.09844
#> ENST00000502987.5   -114.76657  144.09991
#> ENST00000506691.1   -136.59272  443.25939
#> ENSRNOT00000039247 -1032.71401 1362.71401

Created on 2024-04-26 with reprex v2.1.0
Data
df1 <- "                   a_25 a_26 a_27 a_28 a_29 a_30
ENST00000673902.1       26      38      40      38      36      63
ENST00000618500.4        0       0       0       0       0       0
ENST00000420646.6        0      26       0     115       0     220
ENST00000394991.8     3496    2272    4848    2508    2427    3024
ENST00000336904.7       19       0      40      43      61       0
ENST00000394989.6        0       0      27       0       0      40
ENST00000673766.1      220     274     321     338     248     304
ENST00000673718.1       56     197     603     176     437      43
ENST00000674129.1      743     538    1047     202     276     269
ENST00000345009.8        0       0       0       0       0       0
ENST00000394986.5       85      97     277      10      41      63
ENST00000508895.5     3034    2152    5165    1231    1245    1814
ENST00000506244.5      554     283     276     247     248     182
ENST00000505199.5        0       0       0       0       0       0
ENST00000611107.1        0       0       0       0       0       0
ENST00000502987.5      113     128     213     127     139     144
ENST00000506691.1      212     170     397      87     106     126
ENSRNOT00000039247    1623    1230    2239    1413    1573    1611
ENSRNOT00000118428       0       0       0     106     119     132"
df1 <- read.table(text = df1, header = TRUE)

Created on 2024-04-26 with reprex v2.1.0

is it possible to perform a Mann-Whiteney pvalue test for the ratio con1 vs con2 ?

@user3683485 Yes, substitute wilcox.test for t.test in code above.

I will caution against using a Mann-Whitney for this dataset because you'll never reach a p-value of less than 0.1 regardless of the effect size simply because you don't have enough samples. Consider the difference between t.test(1:3, 1001:1003) and wilcox.test(1:3, 1001:1003). Even though that's a huge difference, the rank-order nature of the Mann-Whitney means that it returns a p-value of 0.1.

There's a good answer here by @Rui already but I thought I'd add some additional takes. First of all, they are incorrect to comment that nothing can be done with just 3 data points. Your test will be underpowered, so you'll only be detecting the largest differences, but perhaps you're okay with that. If so, performing individual t-tests like they did is one of your best methods but you do also need to remember to control for the false discovery rate. Here's the code I wrote to do something very similar to their answer:
# Data import and cleaning
# v <- readClipboard()
w <- as.data.frame(strsplit(v, " +"))
names(w) <- w[1,]
x <- t(w[2:7,])
num_data <- as.data.frame(apply(x, 2, as.numeric))
rownames(num_data) <- rownames(x)

# T-testing
pval_data <- cbind(num_data, pval=apply(y, 1, function(row_data){
  t.test(row_data[1:3], row_data[4:6])$p.value
}))
pval_data <- cbind(pval_data, pval_adj=p.adjust(pval_data[,"pval"], method = "fdr"))

                      2    3    4    5    6    7        pval   pval_adj
ENST00000673902.1    26   38   40   38   36   63 0.341415554 0.59338499
ENST00000618500.4     0    0    0    0    0    0         NaN        NaN
ENST00000420646.6     0   26    0  115    0  220 0.245014967 0.53566852
ENST00000394991.8  3496 2272 4848 2508 2427 3024 0.356030993 0.59338499
ENST00000336904.7    19    0   40   43   61    0 0.529568531 0.76237369
ENST00000394989.6     0    0   27    0    0   40 0.802722465 0.80272247
ENST00000673766.1   220  274  321  338  248  304 0.559074037 0.76237369
ENST00000673718.1    56  197  603  176  437   43 0.758191797 0.80272247
ENST00000674129.1   743  538 1047  202  276  269 0.067073885 0.50305413
ENST00000345009.8     0    0    0    0    0    0         NaN        NaN
ENST00000394986.5    85   97  277   10   41   63 0.200133522 0.53566852
ENST00000508895.5  3034 2152 5165 1231 1245 1814 0.147056806 0.53566852
ENST00000506244.5   554  283  276  247  248  182 0.249978641 0.53566852
ENST00000505199.5     0    0    0    0    0    0         NaN        NaN
ENST00000611107.1     0    0    0    0    0    0         NaN        NaN
ENST00000502987.5   113  128  213  127  139  144 0.685631111 0.79111282
ENST00000506691.1   212  170  397   87  106  126 0.155780573 0.53566852
ENSRNOT00000039247 1623 1230 2239 1413 1573 1611 0.633515026 0.79111282
ENSRNOT00000118428    0    0    0  106  119  132 0.003954481 0.05931721

However, it sounded like you may also be interested in the overall difference between the treatments rather than any specific row/measurement. This can be tested with more multivariate statistics, specifically the permutational MANOVA offered by the vegan package:
library(vegan)
adonis2(t(num_data)~c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"))

'nperm' >= set of all permutations: complete enumeration.
Set of permutations < 'minperm'. Generating entire set.
Permutation test for adonis under reduced model
Terms added sequentially (first to last)
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 719

adonis2(formula = t(num_data) ~ c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"))
                                Df SumOfSqs     R2      F Pr(>F)
c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")  1 0.074524 0.4659 3.4893    0.1
Residual                         4 0.085432 0.5341              
Total                            5 0.159956 1.0000   

However, in both cases it's likely that you simply don't have enough power to detect a difference between your treatments if there is a true difference.

Actually i am interested more to see specific gene/row measurements not overall ! Iwant to see for reach row/gene how the expression changes and if there is statistical significance between the two conditions I agree about the statistical power since there are only 3 samples in each condition and as far as I know to find true differences it is necessary to have at least 10..but its something maybe just for the big differences but I see that its difficult to have results with statistically significant differences. Is there any other test more reliable for these data?

@user3683485 Not sure what you mean by “reliable” — there’s really just not that much to do with this small a quantity of data. While it’s not like 10 samples is a magic number because it depends on the size of the effect you’re looking for, more certainly won’t hurt. You can take away from this a ranking of most to least promising genes to follow up on though, in order of increasing p-value. Honestly the best test at the moment is one of intuition and that last one is looking pretty good given the absence of any signal in the one treatment and decent numbers in the other!

If you have strong prior reason to believe that some genes have more or less of an effect than others it may be worth trying some Bayesian stats but those aren’t going to give you any more of a threshold of “these are good, those are bad” than the frequentist statistics shown here.
